# How can this type of screen layout be achieved?

Tags: android, android-layout

[image: Calculator]
<sub>(source: [winsupersite.com](https://winsupersite.com/site-files/winsupersite.com/files/archive/winsupersite.com/content/content/128528/win7/win7_ff_calc_rtm_02.jpg))</sub>

I'm almost done with the view completely, but the problem comes when I've put the "=" Button.
I've used 6 linear layout "horizontal" for each row.

But I can't figure out, how "=" can occupy space from both the layouts!
How's it possible to implement?

For example, to make my question more clear, to implement 0 button, I could do it with specifying it's space! But can't think of anything for "=" button!

Or should I declare the vertical column starting with M- as linear layout with "vertical"?
But then there comes another question! How can that layout occupy only somewhat 10% of the entire screen?

Thanks in advance :)

Here's my code!

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

 <LinearLayout 
    android:orientation = "horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bBackspace"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:text="@string/backspace"
        android:onClick="onButtonPress"
    />
      <Button
        android:id="@+id/bCE"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:text="@string/CE"
        android:onClick="onButtonPress"
    />
      <Button
        android:id="@+id/bClear"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:text="@string/clear"
        android:onClick="onButtonPress"
    />  
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bSign"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:text="@string/sign"
        android:onClick="onButtonPress"
    /> 
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation = "horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b7"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:text="@string/seven"
        android:onClick="onButtonPress"
    />
      <Button
        android:id="@+id/b8"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:text="@string/eight"
        android:onClick="onButtonPress"
    />
      <Button
        android:id="@+id/b9"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:text="@string/nine"
        android:onClick="onButtonPress"
    />  
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bDiv"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:text="@string/div"
        android:onClick="onButtonPress"
    /> 
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation = "horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b4"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:text="@string/four"
        android:onClick="onButtonPress"
    />
      <Button
        android:id="@+id/b5"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:text="@string/five"
        android:onClick="onButtonPress"
    />
      <Button
        android:id="@+id/b6"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:text="@string/six"
        android:onClick="onButtonPress"
    />  
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bMul"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:onClick="onButtonPress"
        android:text="@string/mul"
    /> 
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation = "horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:onClick="onButtonPress"
        android:text="@string/one"
    />
      <Button
        android:id="@+id/b2"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:text="@string/two"
        android:onClick="onButtonPress"
    />
      <Button
        android:id="@+id/b3"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:text="@string/three"
        android:onClick="onButtonPress"
    />  
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bSub"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:text="@string/sub"
        android:onClick="onButtonPress"
    /> 
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation = "horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center">
      <Button
        android:id="@+id/b0"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:text="@string/zero"
        android:onClick="onButtonPress"
    />
      <Button
        android:id="@+id/bPoint"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:onClick="onButtonPress"
        android:text="@string/point"
    />
      <Button
        android:id="@+id/bAdd"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:onClick="onButtonPress"
        android:text="@string/add"
    />   
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation = "horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center">
      <Button
        android:id="@+id/bEquals"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:text="@string/equals"
        android:onClick="onButtonPress"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `But you can open calculator in Win 7`, if we are not running linux. :D Edited your question with an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [TableLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html) instead.  It works the same as HTML tables: you can specify certain cells to stretch over multiple columns or rows.

You'll be using something like this: `android:layout_span="2"`